# Collapse pandas panel into one dataframe, and sort

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to combine x-y coordinates from a grid into one dataframe in pandas.

I have 10 rows of coordinates, with 8-12 columns each. I've got them separated into their own dataframes by row, needing other data per site.

I want to compile a master list of all x-y coordinates.

I combined the dataframes into a panel for ease of use.

I have tried unpacking them and repackaging them using, groupby and for loops, but I keep hitting walls into trying to partition and sort.

This seems too easy to not be a method built already, but pandas.Panel.sort_values does not work as shown below. The docs and online forums don't deal with panels directly; they all break down into dataframes.

What is the simplest way to trim and sort an entire panel into one dataframe?

Thought this may be straightforward without it, but adding code:

Sample Data:

row0:

```
    handle  x   y
0   nullL0  np.nan  np.nan  
1   nullL1  np.nan  np.nan 
2   Handle37c   4.4504  1.0352
3   Handle37d   4.4525  1.5943
4   Handle380   4.4504  2.0032
5   Handle381   4.4525  2.5623
6   Handle384   4.4504  2.9712
7   Handle385   4.4525  3.5303
8   Handle388   4.4504  3.9392
9   Handle389   4.4525  4.4983
10  nullR1  np.nan  np.nan  
11  nullR2  np.nan  np.nan
```

row3:

```
        handle  x   y
0   Handle352   3.0748  0.6158
1   Handle353   3.0727  0.0568
2   Handle356   3.0748  1.5838
3   Handle357   3.0727  1.0248
4   Handle35a   3.0748  2.5518
5   Handle35b   3.0727  1.9928
6   Handle35e   3.0748  3.5198
7   Handle35f   3.0727  2.9608
8   Handle362   3.0748  4.4878
9   Handle363   3.0727  3.9288
10  Handle366   3.0748  5.4558
11  Handle367   3.0727  4.8968

#    Collect all dataframes into one
pn = pd.Panel(df)
```

Would like from here to add a dataframe to the panel that includes only x,y values based on handle as index.

Here are my attempts at partitioning:

```
p = pn.xs('y',axis=2)
q = pn.xs('x',axis=2) # looking at the label on the 2nd axis, 
indx =     pn.xs('handle',axis=2)

# Create zip and then dictionary
df1 = zip(itt.chain(*indx.values),
          itt.chain(*xCoords.values),
          itt.chain(*yCoords.values))

# Add dataframe to panel after munging dataframe out of dict
```

Attempts at sort problem:

```
# cannot get to work!!
pn = pn.sort_values(by=['y']) #,axis=2) 
p = x.groupby("y",axis=0).apply(lambda x : x.sort_values("y"))
```

The y-values aren't sorted in the dataframes, creating added issues shaping the data. The two issues seem related, but they could be very different ends.

To reiterate, I would like to determine how to do this in a panel without having to resort to for-loops or functions.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the goal is but have you tried `pn.to_frame()`? Then maybe some combinations of `stack` ,`unstack`, `reset_index`, `set_index` etc. will get you what you need.

Comment: That's all I needed. I had too many problems merged together: Reseting the index, adding a column with that index, then saving to a csv was as far as I needed.